# How many n-bit binary numbers can be formed such that, for every prefix (position) the number of 0's is at least 'x' times than the number of 1's?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, programming

For ex- 
(1) if n = 5 and x=3
Then 3 such binary nos. are possible, which are-
00000, 00001, 00010
All these nos have no of 0's at least 3 times the no of 1's at any prfix(position)

(2) if n=6 and x=2
Then there are 8 possible binary nos satisfying the given condition-
000000, 000001, 000010, 000011, 000100, 000101, 001000, 001001

Comment: Please LaTeX your question!

Comment: @Culver Kwan  what?

Comment: LaTeX is a language to convert some code into a equation, such as $\sum^{100}_{n=1}n=5050$